# How to correctly response to HTTP request

Tags: c++, sockets, postman

I am trying to create simple server which will repond to every HTTP request with 200 OK. I write code below, but when I called the server with Postman I ended with wrong result. If I do NOT call `closesocket(clientSocket)`, Postman is waiting infinitely long for response with `Sending requst...`. I i do call `closesocket(clientSocket)`, Postman shows `Error: socket hang up`.

What I have to do to correctly close connection?

```
void main()
{
    std::cout << "Start..." << std::endl;;

    int port = 54000;

    // Initialize WinSock
    WSAData data;
    WORD ver = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    int wsResult = WSAStartup(ver, &data);
    if (wsResult != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Can't start Winsock, Err #" << wsResult << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    // Create socket
    SOCKET sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        std::cout << "Can't create socket, Err #" << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }

    // Bind the ip address and port to a socket
    sockaddr_in hint;
    hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
    hint.sin_port = htons(port);
    hint.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    bind(sock, (sockaddr*)&hint, sizeof(hint));
    listen(sock, SOMAXCONN);

    // Wait for a connection
    sockaddr_in client;
    int clientSize = sizeof(client);

    // While loop: accept and echo message back to client
    char buf[16384];

    while (true)
    {
        SOCKET clientSocket = accept(sock, (sockaddr*)&client, &clientSize);
        //print(client);
        ZeroMemory(buf, 16384);

        // Wait for client to send data
        int bytesReceived = recv(clientSocket, buf, 16384, 0);
        if (bytesReceived == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            std::cout << "Error in recv(). Quitting" << std::endl;
            break;
        }

        const char* reply =
            "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n"
            "Content-Type: text/html\n"
            "Content-Length: 0\n"
            "Keep - Alive: timeout=1, max=1\n"
            "Accept-Ranges: bytes\n"
            "Connection: close\n";
        send(clientSocket, reply, strlen(reply), 0);
        //closesocket(clientSocket);
    }   |
}
```

edit. Edited code. I corrected line endings, added better check for `recv` result and also I am checking number of sent bytes (and yes, all bytes are send). I also tried to add `shutdown` function, but result is still the same - infinite waiting or error. When I try to add `do / while` section, I will stuck in infinite waiting for another request. Do you have any other advice?

```
void main()
{
    std::cout << "Start..." << std::endl;;

    int port = 54000;

    // Initialize WinSock
    WSAData data;
    WORD ver = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    int wsResult = WSAStartup(ver, &data);
    if (wsResult != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Can't start Winsock, Err #" << wsResult << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    // Create socket
    SOCKET sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        std::cout << "Can't create socket, Err #" << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }

    // Bind the ip address and port to a socket
    sockaddr_in hint;
    hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
    hint.sin_port = htons(port);
    hint.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    bind(sock, (sockaddr*)&hint, sizeof(hint));
    listen(sock, SOMAXCONN);

    // Wait for a connection
    sockaddr_in client;
    int clientSize = sizeof(client);

    // While loop: accept and echo message back to client
    char buf[16384];

    while (true)
    {
        SOCKET clientSocket = accept(sock, (sockaddr*)&client, &clientSize);
        //print(client);
        ZeroMemory(buf, 16384);

        // Wait for client to send data
        //do {
            bytesReceived = recv(clientSocket, buf, 16384, 0);
            if (bytesReceived > 0)
            {
                std::cout << std::string(buf, 0, bytesReceived) << std::endl;
            }
            else if (bytesReceived == 0)
            {
                std::cout << "Connection closed" << std::endl;
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "Error in recv(). Quitting = " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
                break;
            }
        //} while (bytesReceived > 0);

        const char* reply =
            "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
            "Content-Type: text/html\r\n"
            "Content-Length: 0\r\n"
            "Accept-Ranges: bytes\r\n"
            "Connection: close";
        bytesSent = send(clientSocket, reply, strlen(reply), 0);
        if (bytesSent < 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Send failed = " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << "Sent: " << bytesSent << " (" << strlen(reply) << ")" << std::endl;
        shutdown(clientSocket, SD_BOTH);
        closesocket(clientSocket);
    }   |
}
```

Comment: I think what's happening is recv keeps blocking until has read 16384 bytes, which will never happen. I've never worked with winsock, so I can't really give you an answer.

Comment: @V0_1D not true. `recv()` (on all platforms, not just Windows) will return whatever is available in the socket UP TO 16384 bytes max, so it CAN and WILL return fewer bytes when possible. The caller MUST check the return value to know how many bytes were actually returned.

Answer (score 1):

```
    const char* reply =
        "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n"
        ...
        "Keep - Alive: timeout=1, max=1\n"
        ...
        "Connection: close\n";
    send(clientSocket, reply, strlen(reply), 0);
```

This is not a valid HTTP response for multiple reasons:

- The line ending should be `\r\n` not `\n`.
- The HTTP header should end with an additional `\r\n` (i.e. empty line). This means the HTTP response you send is not complete and thus Postman hangs on waiting for the rest.
- The `Keep - Alive` header has not the valid syntax for a HTTP header. The field name is not allowed to contain spaces.

Apart from that,

- `send` is not guaranteed to send everything in the given buffer, i.e. you should check the return code.
- A `Keep-Alive` header makes no sense at all if `Connection: close` is used.

Note that HTTP is not an ad-hoc protocol but an actual standard. Implementations should follow the standard and thus the developers would need to study the actual standard and not blindly rely on (wrong) assumptions of how things might work. Even if it works with some client it might not work with another one, since some clients adhere more to the standard while others are more tolerant regarding errors.

Comment: Thank you for reply, I tried to corected my code, but result is still the same. Do you have any other advice please? (Corrected code is in edited question)

Comment: @Sk1X1: The "corrected" code is wrongly corrected. Instead of adding the missing `\r\n` at the end of the HTTP header you even removed the existing `\n` at the end of last field of the HTTP header. Again, please study the actual standard. Also you only check for an error in `send` but you don't check for the `send` being incomplete, i.e. if the send size is actually the expected size.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with the shown code.

```
int bytesReceived = recv(clientSocket, buf, 16384, 0);
```

On any TCP socket, HTTP or not, you get no guarantees whatsoever that whatever the other side of the socket sent you, it will get returned in a single `recv()` call.

If, for example, the client sent you the following HTTP request:

```
GET / HTTP/1.0<CR><LF>
Host: localhost<CR><LF>
<CR><LF>
```

Nobody is going to guarantee you that this `recv()` will return this entire thing to you. `recv()` could, for example, return only the "GET" part, and return the value of 3 to indicate that only 3 bytes were received. You are required to call `recv()` as many times as necessary to receive the complete message. The 2nd call to `recv()` could, theoretically, return " `/`" and the value of 2 to indicate that two more bytes were received.

You cannot completely ignore the return code from `recv()`, which tells you what was actually read, and you will need to implement appropriate logic to keep `recv()`ing until you received the entire message. Your code needs to understand that an HTTP message consists of a message line, an arbitrary list of headers, then a single blank line, all terminated by `<CR><LF>`, or "`\r\n`", and keep trying until it receives the complete message.

```
    const char* reply =
        "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n"
        "Content-Type: text/html\n"
        "Content-Length: 0\n"
        "Keep - Alive: timeout=1, max=1\n"
        "Accept-Ranges: bytes\n"
        "Connection: close\n";
```

HTTP uses `<CR><LF>` as the end of line terminator, all of these should be `\r\n`.

"`Keep - Alive:`" is not a valid HTTP header name. Header names cannot contain spaces.

A blank line, a single `\r\n`, should follow the last HTTP header. It is missing fom your response. Even though you're closing the socket immediately, without a well-formed HTTP response message the client can rightfully conclude that the HTTP server is faulty and did not send a valid response.

```
    send(clientSocket, reply, strlen(reply), 0);
```

Like with `recv()`, you are not guaranteed that `send()` will transmit the requested number of bytes. Just like with `recv()` you must check the return value of `send()` to see how many bytes were sent, and then try again to send the remaining part of the message, if there's any, until you send the entire message.

You must fix all of these problems in order to properly implement HTTP over TCP.

Comment: Thank you for reply, I tried to corected my code, but result is still the same. Do you have any other advice please? (Corrected code is in edited question)

Comment: The updated code still fails to fix most of the problems I pointed out.